# What is the (or is there a) difference between [client] and [mysql] groups in mysql option files?

Tags: mysql

MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html) states that client options "can be specified on the command line or in the [mysql] and [client] groups of an option file".

In that case, is there a specific purpose for each of these two option groups, so that one of the following possibilities apply?

- Some options are meant to be specified under `[client]` and others under `[mysql]` (in that case, how to tell which one to use where?)
- Behavior of a given option depends on whether it is used under `[client]` or `[mysql]` (if so, how does it work?)

Or are they actually the same, so that any client option could be specified under either one of these two groups without change in behavior?

Answer (score 3):

The `[client]` group is used by all clients. For instance, both `mysql` and `mysqldump` are client applications.

The `[mysql]` group is only use by the `mysql` command, whereas the `[mysqldump]` group would be used only by the `mysqldump` command.

Option groups are processed in order, so you should put the general group first, then the more specific groups, so that the more specific options will replace the general options.

For full details, see the [Option Files](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html) documentation.